# Prove $a^{\smile \smile} =a $ where $a$ is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So far, I have this :

(applying definition of $\smile$)$a^{\smile \smile} = \{(u,w) | (w,u) \in a\} ^{\smile}$

(applying definition of $\smile$) $a^{\smile \smile} = \{(i,j) | (j,i) \in \{(u,w) | (w,u) \in a\} \}$

...

$a^{\smile \smile} = a$

However, I'm stuck in the second step. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: (1) Titles are for titles, not to be part of the actual question; (2) it might be beneficial to give the definition of $a^\smile$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if $a$ is a collection of ordered pairs then $a^\smile$ is the collection of pairs with their order reversed. Note that $(x,y) \in a^\smile$ if and only if $(y,x) \in a$. Thus
$$
(x,y) \in a^{\smile \smile} \iff (y,x) \in a^\smile \iff (x,y) \in a.
$$
That is,
$$
(x,y) \in a^{\smile \smile} \iff (x,y) \in a.
$$
That's exactly what $a^{\smile \smile} = a$ means.